# Solve for $C$ when $C>2018$:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am stuck on the following question:

> Solve for minimum value of $C$ when $C>2018$:
>
> $$27C\equiv 175\mod 256$$

I have been given this high school problem but I don't know what criterion to use to find a solution of this problem.

Since $(27,256)=1,\;$ I know that this congruence has a solution but I don't know how  to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why it is relevant that $27$ is coprime to $256$?

Comment: Since $27 = 3^3$, I would solve $3k\equiv 1 \bmod 256$.  Then you will be able to solve the problem for $C\equiv 256$.

Comment: It is $27C\equiv -81\pmod{256}$.

Comment: This looks like a contest problem.   Can you cite the source?

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$175\equiv -81\pmod{256}$$
So we have
$$27C\equiv -81\pmod{256}$$Divide both sides by $27$ we have$$C\equiv-3\pmod{256}$$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

\begin{align}
256 &= 27(9) + 13\\
27 &= 2(13) + 1 \end{align}
\begin{align}
1 &= 27 - 2(13)\\
&= 27 -2(256-27(9))  \\
&= 19(27) - 2(256)
\end{align}

Hopefully you can see $27^{-1} \pmod{256}$ from here and take it from here.

Comment: if we know the inverse, then $C \equiv (27^{-1})(175) \pmod{256}$ isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\implies27C\equiv175\pmod8$

$\iff3C\equiv-1\pmod8\equiv-1-8$

$\iff C\equiv-3\pmod8$

If $C=8a-3,27C-175=27(8a-3)-175=216a-256$

Take $\pmod{256}\implies256|216a\iff32|27a\implies32|a$ as $(32,27)=1$

Comment: Why are u starting with $27c=175(mod 8)$

Comment: @Learnmore, As I can take modulo easily with $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The extended Euclidean algorithm establishes from $(27,256)=1$ the equation $1 = a\cdot 27+b \cdot 256$ for some integers $a,b$. Then $a$ is the inverse of 27 modulo 256. Then $c \equiv 27^{-1} \cdot 175 \mod 256$.

The Maple command ''modp'' gives $a=19$.

Answer (score 0):

$27C\equiv 175\mod 256 \iff 27C-256Y=175$

$(27,256)=1$. So, $$256=27.9+13$$
$$27=2.13+1$$
$$\begin{align}
1 &= 27 - 2.13\\
&= 27 -2(256-27.9)  \\
&= 19.27 - 2.256
\end{align}$$
Multiplying $175$,
$$175=175.19.27-175.2.256\iff C=175.19=3325$$

Another approximation:
$$27C\equiv 175\mod 256 \iff 27C-256y=175$$
$$                      \iff -256y\equiv -13y\equiv 175\equiv 13 \mod 27$$
$$\iff -13y-27z=13$$
$$ \iff -27z\equiv -z\equiv 13\mod 13$$
$$z\equiv 0 \mod 13$$
Take $z=13$, find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $256-175=81$. Thus $27C\equiv175$ mod $256$ becomes $27C\equiv-81$ mod $256$.  We can now cancel the $27$, leaving $C\equiv-3$ mod $256$. Finally, $256\times8=2048$, so $C=2045$ is the smallest value of $C\gt2018$ that satisfies the congruence.

Remark: The key thing that makes life simple here is the opening coincidence that $256-175=81=27\times3$. If the numbers had been different, the route to an answer would necessarily be different.